# Tensorflow - casting from int to float strange behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am working on tensorflow 0.12 and am having problem with casting.
The following snippet of code does a strange thing:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant(1)
b = tf.cast(a, tf.float32)
print b.eval()
```

I get a value:
6.86574233e-36

I also tried using `tf.to_float()` and `tf.saturate_cast`. Both gave the same result.

Please help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in TF 1.0.

Comment: Do you run Tensorflow on gpu and if yes what gpu card do you use? With which cuda version was Tensorflow compiled? Sometimes, when using a gpu which is not supported by the cuda version strange things happen without any error messages.

Comment: Hi, I am running on a CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2680

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Code that works fine on other machines gives such weird behavior in mine. Did you get to solve it? How? Thanks!

Comment: @ana no, still haven't solved it. I found that using tf.saturate_cast doesn't cause the problem though

Comment: Have you tried to install different versions of numpy? I am actually setting up TF and I had to reduce numpy to version 1.16 to get rid of Futurewarnings
`pip install numpy==1.16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I see that this is still getting some attention, I should mention that the newer versions of tensorflow do not show this behavior, I suggest working with tensorflow version 1.13 or higher

Answer (score 1):

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant(1, tf.int64)  <--------
b = tf.cast(a, tf.float32)
print b.eval()  # 1.0
```

You need to declare the `dtype` for your `tf.constant`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. When I do that I bet b=0 it seems that whatever type i'm using uint8, uint16, int 32, int64 all give different results after cast

Comment: yes, but the problem is deeper than that. The real issue is reading png images which are saved as uint8. after tf.image.decode_png(path, dtype=tf.uint8) I get good values. but then when I try to cast to float i get garbage

Comment: @aarbelle you should write your real issue in the question. and I think I solved the problem in your question.

Comment: I thank you for your time and effort, but your proposal did not work, so no, you did not solve the problem in my question, had it worked i may have continued to a more elaborate problem, but even this simple task seems to fail.

Comment: @aarbelle can you try tensorflow 1.0? it works for me.

Comment: I will try, Thank you

Comment: -1 it is not required to specify the dtype, that's why the argument is optional. It is auto-inferred. Also _if_ the dtype would have to be specified, this should clearly raise something in tf.constant and would be a bug if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code in python3 and python2 for the same tensorflow version as well the code seems to be working correctly as in both the cases I got the following output for python2

```
print b.eval()
1.0
```

I would suggest checking the tensorflow installation or the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

No error in your program.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant(1)
b = tf.cast(a, tf.float32)
print b.eval()
```

This is an online environment for TF https://codeenv.com/env/run/gXGpnR/
Test your code there to run, use

- click on test_tf.py
- add your code
- in left side CLI, type ipython test_tf.py